# ERROR ITMS-9000: "This bundle is invalid. The IPA format requires a top-level directory named Payload, containing only a .app bundle and optional

Tags: ios, xcode6, application-loader

I already read a lot of error about "ERROR ITMS-9000" in StackOverFlow.

But there is not error which i needed.

I am using both of **Xcode Version 6.1 (6A1052d)** and **Application Loader Version 2.9.1 (441)**

> ERROR ITMS-9000: "This bundle is invalid. The IPA format requires a
>   top-level directory named Payload, containing only a .app bundle and
>   optional plugins in a Plugins directory."

Could you please give me some ideas about this error?

Thanks

Comment: I think … the minimum vers. for App Loader is 3.0

Comment: But i have the same problems with my latest version of Xcode 6

Comment: try to create an .IPA and check/compare with others .IPA the structure (package contents)

Comment: Try to `Validate your Settings..` from the `Editor Menu`, more from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26879764/xcode-creates-wrong-ipa-folder-structure

Answer (score 3):

Already answered elsewhere, you need to add the key :

"LSRequiresIPhoneOS" as a BOOL with the value YES to your target.

Otherwise it seems that you are building for OS X.

Answer (score 0):

I have got this error message(XCode 7.3) because I changed the field "Executable file" in info.plist.

It had to be $(EXECUTABLE_NAME) so that Apple can find the app file correctly.