# Xcode creates wrong IPA folder structure

Tags: ios, xcode6, ipa, mdm

We normally have '`Payload`' folder as root once we unarchive IPA files. However, suddenly Xcode has started creating IPAs with '`Applications`' folder as root. Hence MDM is failing to locate files.

Has anyone has faced a similar issue? We are running Xcode version 6.1.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Make sure the key "LSRequiresIPhoneOS" in the info.plist has the value "YES", and make sure the key has the correct case, i.e., IPhone versus Iphone. Earlier versions of Xcode were not as picky about that.

Answer (score 9):

I assume your **Deployment Target** is 8.0

1. *Validate your Settings* from the **Editor Menu**

[image]

2. Double check ***info.plist*** for the following entries.

[image]

```
CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion | String | 6.0
LSRequiresIPhoneOS | Boolean | YES
```

Without it, the archive export will build an iOS IPA file with the OSX Applications folder.

Answer (score 7):

I followed the steps in this post and other posts (adding CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion and LSRequiresIPhoneOS to .plist file) but nothing worked.  Here is what happened on my end:

I renamed my project and for some reason, the rename seem to "unlink" my .plist file from my project.  I had to go to the project - Info tab and edit the list of parameters there.  Add

```
CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion | String | 6.0
LSRequiresIPhoneOS | Boolean | YES
```

Under

```
Custom iOS Target Properties
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have created .xarchive file using xcode 6.1 and then created .ipa file as per my answer here [How to convert .xcarchive to .ipa for client to submit app to app store using Application Loader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14934808/how-to-convert-xcarchive-to-ipa-for-client-to-submit-app-to-app-store-using-ap/18979076#18979076).

Now i have unarchieved my ipa file and it is having same folder structure as normal one, i.e. folder named "Payload" is available(no any Applications file). Also MDM is also working fine with that. Please check the way you have used, or else try this way.

Comment: I think this depends on the build settings as noted by other answers. However thanks for the suggestion. However, as a side note this needs to be added as a comment not an answer. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did - instead of "zipping up" the project file, go into XCode (I'n on version 7.x), and go to PROJECT >> ARCHIVE - and archive that sucker.

It auto archives as an IPA in the proper structure.

The way I did it before was by ZIPPING it up from the FINDER app, and then changing the extension to IPA -- DONT DO THAT.

Once it's archived (from within XCode), it shows up under ORGANIZER, so go there to submit it to apple as a new build.

This was my fix after half of night of trying to submit with Application Loader and it worked fine - had a dozen other issues prior to this but each issue was knocked off the list one by one, so maybe it wouldn't have submitted had I not fixed those, but the above process submitted the first time I tried it - and that was after using Application Loader probably 15 times with no dice.

Answer (score 0):

I just Clean (Command + Shift + K) the project and the error has not appeared