# iOS submitted build not appearing in iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I've checked other SO threads relating to this topic but haven't found exactly what I'm looking for (also most of those threads are reasonably old).

I've got version 1.0.1 (build xxx02) of my app ready for sale. I uploaded version 1.0.2 (build xxx31) through Xcode (Organizer) and it said Submission Successful, 3 days ago.

However, I still can't spot it anywhere within iTunes Connect. I used to be able to see submission history but now I can't seem to see that either.

[image]

What's happening?

Comment: it takes a couple of hours to appear in ItunesConnect. When it's available you will receive an email.

Comment: I uploaded the build 3 days ago. Still doesn't show up in iTunes.

Comment: why not upload a new one

Comment: Doesn't really address the problem...

Comment: Sometimes due to technical Glitch at apple , build takes while to appear in list, either you can wait or push a new build with new build number.

Answer (score 0):

Change the version number because this version number already ready for sale so when ever you are change the version number and upload the build that is successfully uploaded on itunes with new version number.

Comment: Sorry I should've mentioned that I did change the version number (as well as the build number) in the last upload. Changed the version to 1.0.2. I've updated my question to include this info.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with Version number or else. I faced such type of problem many times to upload build on iTunes connect.

**Simple solution is** ,

Try to upload build once again with Xcode and check **Activity** tab. if you can see it like , **build is processing in Activity tab** then  **wait** else **try to upload again**.

Before 5 day i tried to upload build with xcode almost 4 to 5 times and then  i can able to see build processing in Activity tab.

and **Another solution is** , Try to upload build with Application Loader.

For information regarding Upload build with application loader check below link,

[Upload build with Application Loader](http://help.apple.com/itc/apploader/)

---

**Edit 1 :-** to check how to make proper .ipa file with iTunes. then check this link ,

[Make .ipa file with iTunes.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36613320/4910767)

Comment: Sigh. Now getting a `ERROR ITMS-90174: "Missing Provisioning Profile - Apps must contain a provisioning profile in a file named embedded.mobileprovision."` Nothing has changed on my end. So sick of Apple.

Comment: Lol. ! clean project then build once again and then create archive. still you are getting error then select provision profile manualy in build setting.

Comment: Tried cleaning and re-creating archive. Same issue (see http://i.imgur.com/OhatInB.png). Tried Application Loader. It gives me `ERROR ITMS-90072: "The IPA is invalid. It does not include a Payload directory."` (see http://i.imgur.com/cQVC6jP.png).

Comment: yes. because your ipa is not accurate . How you are making .ipa ?? use itunes to make ipa. just drag and drop your application.app file to itunes and then it will convert it into .ipa and then upload it.

Comment: In the past, I've uploaded via Application Loader the same way and it has worked. From within Organizer, I select the archive and click Export, which lets me export to a .ipa. I then select it within AL to upload. But now, it doesn't work, so I'll try your method.

Comment: Sorry this is the first time I'm hearing about uploading via iTunes. Could you elaborate more on how I do this? I've tried to drag/drop my .app into iTunes but it doesn't do anything.

Comment: @Ash what is the status ? is it not helpful for you ?

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get it up on iTunes Connect via Application Loader. It was giving me the error `ERROR ITMS-90072: "The IPA is invalid. It does not include a Payload directory."`. Resolved it with the help of this thread:
[Xcode creates wrong IPA folder structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26879764/xcode-creates-wrong-ipa-folder-structure/28481842#28481842)